# Tensorflow - How to batch the dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing a convolution neural network for digit recognition. I want to train an image dataset but I don't know how to **"batch"** the training data.

I get two arrays storing the train_image and train_label:

```
print train_image.shape
# (73257, 1024)
# where I have 73257 images with size 32x32=1024

print train_label.shape
# (73257, 10)
# Digit '1' has label 1, '9' has label 9 and '0' has label 10
```

Now, I want to batch the training data with batch size = 50

```
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    train_image_batch, train_label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([train_image,
       train_label, batch_size = 50, capacity = 50000, min_after_dequeue = 10000)
```

When I print out the train_image_batch

```
print train_image_batch
# Tensor("shuffle_batch:0", shape=(50, 73257, 1024), dtype=unit8)
```

I expect the shape should be `(50, 1024)`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're using the `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` wrong. It does not expect a `total_size * image_size` dimensions. It expects the training examples to be enqueued through something like a `RecordReader()`. Check out [this blog](https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/)

Answer (score 1):

`shuffle_batch` expects single sample by default. To enforce it to accept multiple samples pass `enqueue_many=True`. Refer [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch)

```
train_image_batch, train_label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [train_image, train_label], batch_size = 50, enqueue_many=True, capacity = 50000, min_after_dequeue = 10000)

print(train_image_batch.shape)

Output:
(50, 1024)
```