# How to correctly batch a tensorflow dataset shape of images

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a batch dataset from a tensor dataset and having trouble with the shape.
I saw some [references to enqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278506/tensorflow-how-to-batch-the-dataset) but a couple years out of date and the tf.dataset.batch doesn't have any options.  My dataset looks like:

```
X_test1 = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensors((X_test_images, X_test_labels))
<TensorDataset shapes: ((5512, 256, 256, 3), (5512,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

Which is image arrays of 256 x 256 with 3 color channels and a label vector for 5512 images / labels.

But when I try to batch it, it creates a new dimension:

```
new = X_test1.batch(32)
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 5512, 256, 256, 3), (None, 5512)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

What I really want is:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

Where the None is the batch 32, with maybe some remainder in the last batch.

Thanks!!

Comment: I have a similar problem, can you please help me? My dataset is like this  `<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>` Here what does `None` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the dataset using from_tensor_slices:

```
X_test1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
new = X_test1.batch(32)
```

Here the [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices)

Comment: Thanks! I should have looked through that page in more detail, now it makes more sense!